# How to return JSON in a Symfony2 Controller

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony, silex

I'm working on a PHP application that was developed a while ago and is running fine in production.  However, now that I've pulled the code down and am running it on my local machine using MAMP, some things are not working.  I've narrowed many of my problems down to the Symfony2, v 2.2.0 controller.  When I console.log the output of the ajax that is calling my controller, I get a plain string version of the JSON.  If I go into the ajax and add the parameter `dataType: 'json'`, then the string is turned into a JSON object and my code works fine.  But, if you look at the controller, shouldn't JSON be the output at that level?  Can you help me understand what the problem is?  I suspect is has something to do with using a newer version of PHP or something like that.

Tech:
PHP Version 5.5.3
Silex
Symfony2 Version 2.2.0

Controller

```
$dashboard->post('/add-food', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    $user = UserUtils::getUser($app, $app['session']->get('userId'));
    $data = array(
        'foodTypeId' => $request->request->get('foodTypeId'),
        'addFoodAmount' => $request->request->get('foodAmount'),
        'goal' => $user->getGoal(),        
        'people' => mround($user->getAdults() + ($user->getChildren() / 2), 1), 
    );
    $retValue = StorageUtils::updateFoodType($app, $data, 'add'); 
    $foodType = $retValue['foodType'];
    $result = array(
        'foodTypeId' => $foodType->getId(),
        'userHas' => $foodType->getUserHas(),
        'categoryPerc' => StorageUtils::updateFoodCategoryPerc($app, $foodType->getFoodCategory()->getId()),
        'categoryId' => $foodType->getFoodCategory()->getId(),
        'totalPerc' => StorageUtils::getTotalFoodPerc($app, $user->getId()),
        'successMsg' => $retValue['successMsg'],
    );

    if ($result) {
        return $app->json($result, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
    } else {
        return new Response('failure', 200);
    }
});
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app/dashboard/add-food",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    success: function(data) {
        $(window).colorbox.close();
        updatePage(data);
    }
});
```

When I look at the header I get the following:
Connection: Keep-Alive
**Content-Type: text/html**
Date: 2014 Feb 26 12:49:01
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.5.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.3

Output:
`{"foodTypeId":316342,"userHas":39,"categoryPerc":74.2,"categoryId":61659,"totalPerc":11.5,"successMsg":"1 gals of Vegetable Oil has been added."}`

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Can you use JsonResponse class.I am not sure about this class in 2.2

Comment: try to `json_encode` your `$result` array

Comment: what is your `$app` variable?  without knowing what that variable does, we can't know what it is returning

Comment: @abbiya @Sehael, he is using Silex. `$app->json()` uses `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Edited.  Yes, I'm using Silex.

Comment: The thing that is funny is that the current state of the code used to work and I haven't upgraded any of the tech except for maybe the MAMP environment where I just downloaded the latest version.